# Rails render in controller#create is not loading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form being submitted by the resident of a condominium to apply a pass for a visitor.

Upon submission I have setup the controller to render a template or redirect it to another path depending on the input of the form and display a flash message on the top of the page after clicking the submit button.

Somehow redirect works fine but render does nothing to the page.

Did try flash.now with render but no flash and it looks like it is not loading anything new on the page.

```
class VisitorPassesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @visitor_pass = VisitorPass.new
    @controller = "visitor_passes"
  end

  def create
    unless resident && correct_resident_key?
     flash[:danger] = "Invalid resident key."
     # render 'new'                     doesn't work 
     # render action: 'new'             doesn't work
     redirect_to new_visitor_pass_path  works
     redirect_to '/visitor_passes/new'  works
     return
    end
    .
    .
    . 
  end 
end
```

Here is the output of the console.

```
Rendering visitor_passes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered visitor_passes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb
Resident Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "residents".* FROM "residents" WHERE "residents"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 155], ["LIMIT", 1]] app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:17:in 'current_user'
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 3.1ms | Allocations: 760)
Completed 200 OK in 429ms (Views: 59.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 33936)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash messages are displayed in the next response cycle (ie after a redirect). If you want to display a flash message in response to the current request use [ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash#now](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now).

```
class VisitorPassesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @visitor_pass = VisitorPass.new
    # just use the controller_name method provided by rails instead
  end

  def create
    # ...
    # prefer positive conditions instead of negative          
    if resident && correct_resident_key?
      # do something awesome
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid resident key."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Also make sure you are using the `local: true` option on the form if using `form_with` as it defaults to those pesky XHR `remote: true` requests.

Comment: The problem was the local: true was not set on my form! Thanks!